# Can't write to a csv file from a class in kotlin

Tags: csv, kotlin

Im trying to write a class to csv. And I need or at least prefer a class that I could call that could both retrieve and eventually save the class objects as csv.

I have tried every imaginable way I can find to write files. Everytime it works flawlessly in the main activity .kt, but soon as I move any of it to a dedicated class I get:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference`

or I get told thats is a read only file system.

Heres a copy of a class that ive tried and gotten the error.

```
package com.example.jobndays

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.PrintWriter

class DryTest: AppCompatActivity() {

   fun main() {

      var fileInputStream: FileOutputStream? = null
      fileInputStream = openFileOutput("bobbin.csv", MODE_PRIVATE)
      val bob = "fella"
      fileInputStream.write(bob.toByteArray())

   }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a snippet of code to show what is not working and potentially your earlier attempts?

Comment: Sure, thank you for looking. Don't mind the variable names, this is just the test with class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found an answer. Apparently in order to write files you need 'context', not entirely sure why, but just ask for it and stick infront of stuff that says they're unresolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).